# Program To Identify Lower Case Strings

Tags: c++, string, boolean, uppercase, lowercase

Beginner C++ student here, first ever programming class. I am trying to put together a program that will identify if a string is all lower case or not. I got as far as the code below. However, I need to account for spaces " ". If there is a space in the string that is input by the user, the program is suppose to return that it is not all lower case. Example:

input: abc def
return: The string is not lower case.

Would any of you ever so kindly advise what would be the best way to account for this in the code below?

NOTE: I know I have 'included' some extra header files, but that is because this is going to be part of another program and this is just an excerpt to get things running.

Thank you so very much all!!

```
 #include <fstream>
 #include <iostream>
 #include <string>
 #include <cstdlib>
 #include <algorithm>
 #include <cctype>
 #include <iomanip>

 using namespace std;

 bool die(const string & msg);


 bool allLower(const string & l);

 int main() {

     string l;

    cout << "\nEnter a string (all lower case?): ";
     cin >> l;

     if (allLower(l) == true)
     {
         cout << "The string is lower case." << endl;
     }
     else
     {
         cout << "The string is not lower case." << endl;
     }



 }



 bool allLower(const string & l) {

     struct IsUpper {
         bool operator()(int value) {
             return ::isupper((unsigned char)value);
         }
     };

     return std::find_if(l.begin(), l.end(), IsUpper()) == l.end();

 }

 bool die(const string & msg){
     cout << "Fatal error: " << msg << endl;
     exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
 }
```

Comment: Just like `::isupper` there are functions like `::isspace` to check for spaces

Answer (score 0):

You could use a good old fashion for-loop.

```
bool allLower(const std::string & l)
{
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < l.size(); i++)
    {
        if(l[i] == ' ')
        {
            return false;
        }
        else if(isalpha(l[i]))
        {
            if(isupper(l[i]))
                return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Note that if you feed it in something like "2" it will return true. You could add a final else statement that returns false if you so desire.

Answer (score 0):

You can check to see if a character is alphabetic using the function std::isalpha() prior to using std::isupper() or std::islower() to checking whether all letters within your string are uppercase/lowercase, etc

Answer (score 0):

A range-based for loop would be clearer than indices IMO

```
bool allLower(const std::string &l)
{
    for (auto c : l)
    {
        if ((c == ' ') ||
            (std::isalpha(c) && std::isupper(c)))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```